# Flask SQLAlchemy combining Datetime with same Date and returning all rows as a tuple for that date

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a table called ‘Status’ which has a column ‘created_at’ which is a DateTime() object.  I want to query this table and pull out a list of tuples where each tuple is grouped by the same Date()… so far I have the following:

```
db.session.query(Status,func.count(Status.created_at)).group_by(cast(Status.created_at, Date).desc()).all()
```

This gives me a tuple which consist of a Status element and the number of those statuses that have the same date.  Here is an example output:

```
[(<Status(id:1, user_id:2, subject_id:2, updated_at:2016-01-07 01:12:27)>, 3), (<Status(id:3, user_id:2, subject_id:1, updated_at:2016-01-06 16:21:53)>, 2)]
```

What I really want for the entry is something like the following

```
[(<Status(id:1, user_id:2, subject_id:2, updated_at:2016-01-07 01:12:27)>, <Status(id:2, user_id:2, subject_id:1, updated_at:2016-01-07 01:12:27)>, <Status(id:9, user_id:2, subject_id:3, updated_at:2016-01-07 01:12:27)>), (<Status(id:3, user_id:2, subject_id:1, updated_at:2016-01-06 16:21:53)>, <Status(id:8, user_id:2, subject_id:2, updated_at:2016-01-06 16:21:53)>)]
```

in other words instead of the number of statuses on that date I want all the actual statuses as a tuple.

Many Thanks,
Drew Butcher

Comment: try joining table on it self and doing a `filter(Status.created_at == Status.created_at)`

Comment: What dbms are you using?

Comment: When I did @Busturdust suggestions I got the following:     sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Can't join table/selectable 'statuses' to itself

Comment: @DrewButcher Are you sure you did it right? self joins should be allowed. try something along the lines of `session.query(Status,Status).filter(Status.id == Status.id).filter(Status.created_at == Status.created_at)`

Answer (score 0):

You can only get list of ids (or any another column).

Postgresql:

```
session.query(func.array_agg(Status.id), func.cast(Status.created_at, Date)).group_by(func.cast(status.created_at, Date))
```

MySQL:

```
session.query(func.group_concat(Status.id), func.cast(Status.created_at, Date)).group_by...
```

The first returns result like this:

```
[((1,2,3), date1), ((4,5,6), date2),... ]
```

And the second almost the same, but the first result column is string, like '1,2,3' instead of tuple.

Well, next step is query, where you will get list of Status objects for every date (row) of result above

UPD. As you say, your DBMS is MySQL, you should split string with ids, as step 1.1:)

Comment: db.session.query(func.group_concat(Status.id), func.cast(Status.created_at, Date)).group_by(func.cast(status.created_at, Date)).all() gave me back [('1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10', datetime.date(2016, 1, 7))] which is all the statuses and the latest date.

Comment: @DrewButcher group_by(func.cast(Status.created_at, Date)). Uppercase :)